# How to remove firebase event listener without a reference to it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**My situation is** I have some firebase database event listeners that I start when the app starts. These keep user data in sync across devices. I also have a service that will very occasionally be called. It uploads a lot of data. I want to turn off the listeners when I start the service so they don't go crazy. It's the same data; I can't just use different locations.

**My question is** how can I close them? I figure I need to either close the listeners without a reference to them (doesn't seem possible that I've found) **OR** maintain a reference to the ChildEventListener objects somehow AND access that reference from the Service.

If it's any help, both the service and data event listeners are being initiated right after the application starts. Is there a way to pass non-primitive data to the Service? Intent extras are 'copies' so that seems like a dead end. Do I make a static reference to the ChildEventListeners in the Application class? How would I best do that if that's the way to go?

Comment: add all listeners to a arraylist or mutablelist. then on destroy cancel all the listners

Comment: akash - your solution is for a common but DIFFERENT question (to keep listeners active only when an certain Activity is active). My question is different; I don't want my listeners to go away when an Activity is destroyed, I want them to go away when a Service is started.

Comment: Please show some code to go along with your description. It doesn't need to be a fully functioning app, but it should show enough context about how you create these listeners and where you want to stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop a listener if you don't have the actual ValueEventListener or ChildEventListener object to pass to `removeEventListener()`.  You'll have to store them in some sort of global or singleton so that they can be accessed from the relevant parts of your program that needs to use them.

Comment: Well that's helpful to at least know which path I have to go down. Thanks!